# Am I doing this hypothesis test correctly?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing, p-value

I am attempting to perform a hypothesis test to see if an activity improves the mood of people.

Null Hypothesis: The activity does not effect the mood.

Alternate Hypothesis: The activity improves the mood.

I have a sample of $60$ people and asked them to give their mood on a scale of 1-5 before and after performing the activity, with $1$ being a poor mood, and $5$ being a very good mood.

The scores before the activity have a mean of $3.26$ and a standard deviation of $0.52$.

The scores after the activity have a mean of $4.82$ and a standard deviation of $0.39$.

I calculate my Z-score as:

$${{4.82-3.26}\over{0.52/\sqrt{60}}} = 23.23$$

I then go to look up the $p$-value for this Z-score, but obviously the table does not show Z-scores as high as this meaning that the $p$-value is very close to $1$.

Can I then reject my null hypothesis based on this?

Comment: You should be enforcing a matched pairs $t$ test in your hypothesis test, not a two independent sample $z$ test. On the other hand, note that you're dealing with likert (non$-$normal) data, so you'll want to refer to a non$-$parametric test alternative to the matched pairs $t$ test which is the paired samples Wilcoxon test. You can google this test to see how it's used in practice.

Comment: Ok thank you. I implemented this and found similar results - the p-value is very small (e.g. $1.7e^{-10}$), so I assume that it is safe to say that I can reject the null hypothesis with extremely high confidence.